# Prevent users from editing major version

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, versioning

Is it possible to prevent users from editing a major version of a document? Basically, what I want to be able to do is that when a user changes a draft version to a major version I want the document to become read only (or something to that effect) without having to change the permissions to that file.

Is this possible in SharePoint Foundation 2010?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

When you save a major version back to SharePoint with edits, it becomes a new minor version.  They'd have to explicitly overwrite to go over the major version which is doable.

I don't think this behavior is changeable in any way out of the box.  One possible workaround is to kickoff a workflow to a library that is locked by permissions to all but the workflow account that will move the major version into that library when the new major version is saved.